# Using DbParameter w/ ExecuteSqlCommand in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be any documentation for ExecuteSqlCommand, I could only find documentation for [FromSql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql).  I'm able to successfully call a stored procedure using ExecuteSqlCommand with named parameters that returns rows affected.

However, I'm attempting to change the Direction property of one DbParameter to ParameterDirection.Output.  This doesn't appear to work and I can find no examples anyway of this usage.  The closest I saw was [issue #3115](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3115) in the EF Core GitHub repo, but there was no usage of out parameters.

Of course I can use DbCommand to achieve this, but does ExecuteSqlCommand only use DbParameter for named parameters and direction is ignored?  If so, then ideally this should be documented somewhere - maybe the Raw SQL Queries article can be expanded upon.

Comment: AFAIK, just setting the direction to out should work with `.FromSql()`. You may want to [submit a new issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/new) showing the code you're using.

Comment: There is an outstanding [Connector/NET bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75267) preventing it working for MySQL.

Comment: Fixed in commit [MySqlParameter with Direction=Output does not work for text commands](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/commit/91d3321e0a40d9c48e1a8203eb7774c7a311c38e) for release 8.0.32 of Connector/NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a database provider specific issue since it doesn't work for MySQL, but works for SQL Server.  Below is code that demonstrates use for the latter:

```
var outParam = new SqlParameter("@ParamOut", DbType.Int32)
    { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };

ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC dbo.MyTest @ParamOut OUTPUT", outParam);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this in a database provider agnostic manner:

```
    using DbCommand dbCommand = context.Database
        .GetDbConnection()
        .CreateCommand();

    DbParameter outputParam = dbCommand.CreateParameter();
    outputParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
    outputParam.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int32;
```